# How to use ssh to run different robot file's cases in robotfamework at once

Tags: robotframework

I need to use `ssh` to run several cases in different robot test files in robotframework at once so that I can get one HTML report to include all results.

To run one case, I used `robot -t 'b01' bb.robot`

I don't know how to run more than one test case.

`aa.robot`:

```
*** Settings ***
Resource          ../common/App-Request.robot

*** Test Cases ***
a01case
    #add new 

a02case
    #add new 2
    ${erId}    create new user
```

======================================================================

`bb.robot`:

```
*** Settings ***
Resource          ../common/App-Request.robot

*** Test Cases ***
b01case
    #add new 

b02case
    #add new 2
    ${erId}    create new user
```

I expect a command like `robot -t 'b01' bb.robot && 'a01' aa.robot` to run several test cases in different robot test files.

Comment: Robot should accept multiple -t parameters. Have you tried robot -t a01case -t b01case aa.robot bb.robot

Comment: Why do you think you need to use ssh? Is there a reason you want to run the tests separately rather than one after the other?

Comment: @Pekka THANK YOU SOOOOO MUCH ! " robot -t a01case -t b01case aa.robot bb.robot" can work !!!